# New close/flag dialogs have much smaller draggable title areas

Tags: bug, design, close-dialog, flag-dialog

The new close/flag dialogs have much smaller draggable title areas. We used to be able to click between the dialog title and the top border in order to move the dialog, now clicking in that area will select text instead. It looks to be about 20px high. If that area at the top of the dialogs could be made draggable again that would be great.

Comment: Why do you need this tiny margin to be draggable? The title of the modal is huge and is still click-and-draggable.

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be draggable, but it used to be, and that's what I and probably others got used to. Not that I would deliberately click the margin instead of the title, just that if I did it would work. Now half the time I miss the actual title and can't drag the dialog. It requires more precision than it used to. So if they can make it draggable again, great.